Can't solve a 429 response error when trying to use Open AI API
I have been trying to call the Open AI API to provide a response from a pre loaded string onClick from a Button on my Home Screen. Currently I am getting continual 429 response errors that I cannot solve
Here is how I am currently calling it in my ViewModel
@HiltViewModel
class HomeScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(private val openAiApi: OpenAiApi) : ViewModel() {

    private val _responses = mutableStateOf(listOf<String>())
    val responses: State<List<String>> get() = _responses

    fun askQuestion(question: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = fetchWithBackoff(
                OpenAiRequest(
                    model = Constants.OpenAiApi.CHATGPT_MODEL, messages = listOf(
                        Message("user", question)
                    )
                )
            )
            val newMessage = response?.choices?.firstOrNull()?.message?.content ?: "Error: Could not retrieve a response."
            _responses.value = _responses.value + newMessage
        }
    }

    private suspend fun fetchWithBackoff(
        request: OpenAiRequest,
        retries: Int = 3
    ): OpenAiResponse? {
        var retryCount = 0
        var waitTime = 1000L

        while (retryCount < retries) {
            try {
                return openAiApi.postQuestion(request)
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                if (e.code() == 429 || e.code() == 403) {
                    Log.d("OPEN_AI", e.code().toString())
                    delay(waitTime)
                    waitTime *= 2
                    retryCount++
                } else {
                    Log.d("OPEN_AI", e.toString())
                    throw e
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("OPEN_AI", "Success")
        return null
    }

}

and here is how I am calling it in my Home Screen
fun HomeScreen(
    viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel
) {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val response by viewModel.responses

    Log.d("OPEN_AI", response.toString())

Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.askQuestion("Respond with confirmation message if test is successful")
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Test Open AI Response")
                }
}

My logs are continually showing a 429 error.
I have added a fetchWithBackoff to try and stop the app spamming the API with calls, I have added credit balance to my profile on Open AI so there is balance there to use. I cannot seem to get around this issue

Does this answer your question? OpenAI API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"
